# Proper fitting of the timing belt on the car before rotating the engine

Tags: timing, belt

I edited my question because I had asked the wrong question. I know how to take up the slackness of belt by rotating the engine by hand and adjusting the belt tensioner bolt. This is not what I want to know here. I have learnt them in my previous question thanks to my friend HandyHowie.

What I need to know here is the very stage of just putting the belt on the pulleys and sprockets correctly. Do you pull the belt a little bit by hand to install it **straight and level** between the pulleys and prevent to shape it like a **curved** line?

[image]

This is what I need to know:

****When sliding on the new belt, keep the slack near the tension pulley — all other belt running should be tight. This will help keep proper alignment as the tensioner pulley is tightened**.
**

Source:
https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/r/car-projects/how-to-change-a-timing-belt

Comment: I went through this with you in your previous question, what didn’t you understand? https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/82921/tightening-belt-tensioner-after-fitting-new-timing-belt

Comment: I hope you haven’t done this on your engine.  If you have, your belt is likely to slip.

Comment: @handyhowie I understood what you told me at that topic. It was regarding the tensioner not the belt. I thought it is better to create another topic which focuses in belt tension before tightening the tensioner bolt. No, I haven't done anything on my engine yet. Don't worry.

Comment: If you are still not sure how to tension the belt, please do ask more specific questions.  Do not try to change the belt unless you are absolutely certain about what you are doing.  However, if you follow the instructions from the manual that you posted in your previous question, to the letter, you should have no problems.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing (finding detailed information before taking action). There is only one thing left that I'm not sure of. It is proper way of installing the belt on the car (I mean the very initial stage of just putting the belt on the pulleys before rotating the engine by hand or anything else). There should be a certain number of teeth between pulleys and sprockets. You can't just put the belt and tighten the tensioner. I don't know if I could communicate what I mean or not. It is very important.

Comment: @Solar Mike I need more information about the initial stage of installing the belt on the car. It seems like the easiest stage but there are some important points.

Comment: @HandyHowie - Is there any way we can chat together here? It will be more convenient for me to communicate what I mean.

Comment: @HandyHowie - This is what I don't understand:  """ When sliding on the new belt, keep the slack near the tension pulley — all other belt running should be tight. This will help keep proper alignment as the tensioner pulley is tightened. """ Source: https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/r/car-projects/how-to-change-a-timing-belt

Comment: The pulleys for the crank and cam need to stay in the correct relative angular position.  For example, if there are supposed to be 20 free belt teeth between the cam pulley and the crank pulley, then if you put the belt on loose like in your curved green line so that there are 21 belt teeth between the 2 pulleys. When you tension the belt, one of the pulleys will move out of the correct alignment, it will be at an incorrect angle compared to the other pulley.

Comment: @HandyHowie - This was exactly what I wanted to know. Everyone explained how to adjust the belt tension which was not my question here. My problem was to seat the belt teeth correctly between the pulleys.

Comment: My solution for this problem is to mark the old belt and the pulleys in white color and then transfer the marks to the new belt before installing it on the car. This way it is much easier to install the new belt with confidence without worrying about skipping a tooth.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend putting any sort of mark on the new belt, you don’t know whether the mark/paint will cause a deterioration of the rubber, which could cause a weakness and early failure.

Comment: @HandyHowie - I don't use any kind of paint, I only stick very small labels on the belt (like labels on food cans) and remove them after installation. Does this damage the belt?

Answer (score 2):

No, your way is not the correct way of doing this.

It's very simple. Once the belt is installed, rotate the engine in the proper rotation (most are clockwise) from the crankshaft for two turns. This puts all the slack on the tensioner side. This also gives you another chance to double check the timing without the engine going crunch.

The very best way to know you are doing it right is to follow the repair manual. While what I've stated is true of *most* engines with timing belts, *it won't be true for **ALL** engines with timing belts*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm completely aware of engine rotation procedure. Here, I'm talking about whatever should be done before engine rotation. You said once the belt is installed ....... I'm exactly talking about this stage. How do you install the belt on the car properly? There must be a certain number of belt teeth between each pulley. For example, if there are 15 teeth of space between fuel and exhaust pulleys, you have to install the belt that way. If you install it in a way that there are 14 teeth between the pulleys, it will be loose and slack.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian - No, that's not what your question asked. It asked if your procedure is correct for taking up the slack in the belt, and it's not. You take up the slack in the belt by rotating the engine. Before that, you need to get the belt onto the cogs correctly, so the engine stays in time. As long as the engine is in time, there's no issue.

Comment: I think I have problem communicating what I mean. How should I get the belt on the cogs correctly? By pulling the belt by hand and choosing the longest and the most straight path between each pulley or the other way?

Comment: Usually by starting at the crankshaft and going the opposite of engine rotation, in most cases counterclockwise. This makes the belt tight on the proper side. Yes, the slack remains on the tensioner side. You can never get *all of the slack* out of it, which is why you rotate the engine before setting the tensioner.

Comment: I added a picture to my question. The correct way of putting the belt between the pulleys is to choose the most straight path with the shortest number of teeth between them (like the blue line I have specified in the picture). It is also possible to choose a curved path and put the belt like the green line like in the picture with the higher number of teeth between the pulleys. So, to prevent this, you have pull the belt a little bit by hand to install it straightly.